# Why onReceive method isn't called when screen of my phone is off?

Tags: android

I was debugging my app and I have experienced an interesting issue. I had a breakpoint in my `onReceive` method and the program has stopped there only when screen of my phone was turned on (awake).

Why is that?

If by any chance you would need my code:

```
 private void gcmInit() {

    mRegistrationProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.registrationProgressBar);
    mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mRegistrationProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences
                    .getBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
            if (sentToken) {
               // mInformationTextView.setText(getString(R.string.gcm_send_message));
            } else {
               // mInformationTextView.setText(getString(R.string.token_error_message));
            }
        }
    };

   if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }

}
```

Plus I have also these 2 methods in my MainActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

My Manifest, where I register the receiver:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- GCM START -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.android.bluetoothchat" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.android.gcm.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.example.android.gcm.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.example.android.gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>

    <!-- GCM END -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"

        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".DeviceListActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/select_device"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"/>

</application>
```

Comment: You instantiated a receiver, but you never registered it to your context. Use the context.registerReceiver() method.

Comment: Thank you. What should I use as an IntentFilter parameter?

Comment: I am trying this: this.registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(getCallingPackage()));

Comment: Your intent filter should specifically specify what filter you want to use. You definitely don't want a broadcastReceiver to call the `onReceive` method for every Android intent. You specify which specific intent action you want to hook into as an intent filter. Additionally, if you are using `this.registerReceiver()`, your receiver is running in the context of your activity so if you activity is not on the screen, the receiver will not trigger. If it's doing a task that requires background task even if your activity is not on the screen, declare it in your manifest instead of doing it by code

Comment: By declaring the receiver in your manifest within the application tag, the receiver resides in the context of your application and will be always running in a "separate" process. If you need to dynamically register a receiver, instead of `this.registerReceiver()`, you can use `getApplicationContext().registerReceiver()`. Also note that in this case, your receiver does not initally run until the user actually launches the app for the first time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I have registered the receiver in my manifest though, please check my update.

Comment: I have solved it by removing that onPause and onResume methods which were in official android example (https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MainActivity.java). Thanks a lot for your help, I just solved it because of you.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your problem! I wasn't able to see your `onResume() onPause()` methods, but yeah you were unregistering the receiver on `onPause()` (which is called when your screen turns off and device becomes idle) which is why the receiver didn't run while your screen was turned off.

Comment: Please feel free to answer my question, I will accept it.